# Оценка сложности алгоритма(задачи с тригонометрическими функциями)

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Разбираю примеры решения задач на поиск сложности алгоритма. Задание такое: "Найти короткую запись через Θ, если такой не существует, объяснить почему, и записать через О". Вот примеры которые мне непонятны.

[image: р]

В разборе задач пишут вот такие решения. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, почему в примере е) дается оценка O(n)? Ведь функция и снизу и сверху ограничена c*n(c - константа). Почему не Θ тогда? Также не понимаю почему в примере f) в котором дана только верхняя оценка(и как раз не видно как же снизу ограничить эту функцию) используется Θ вместо О. Это опечатка может или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Классно эту тему рассказывают на www.khanacademy.org , единственная беда  на англ и я прошел тесты и забыл :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположительно это именно опечатки, а именно:

- в примере *e* должна быть указана *Θ* вместо *О*, так как даны функции ограничивающие сверху и снизу, где *Ω = Θ = О*;
- а в примере *f* должна быть указана *О* вместо *Θ*, потому что указана лишь её верхняя граница, которую-то и проще найти чем нижнюю.